# Prevent scene transition when passing props react-native-router-flux

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend

I am struggling with a problem when trying to combine listview with react-native-router-flux

**Expected behaviour**

I use Action.SCENE_NAME to pass props from parent to child, it works perfect on phone.

But in tablet, I use split view. The result I want as follows:

In the left side is parent, in the right side is child. When I click on the left side, it should
display immediately on right side without any transition animation.
[Screen shot of tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJFhn.png)

**Actual behaviour**

Display on tablet
When I click the left side, it raises transition animation to child component
How can I prevent it?

Here is my code:

```
renderRow(rowData) {
        return (   
                 <View style={styles.generalStyle}>
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => {
                        if (window.width <= 600) {

                             Actions.calendarDetail({ eventtop: rowData });
                        } else if (window.width > 600) {      
                            // HOW CAN I PASS PROPS TO <TabletComponent />;
                            // without causing any transition animation
                        }
                     }}>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.evenType}>
                                 {rowData.EventType}
                             </Text>
                             <Text style={{ ...styles.contentStyle, ...styles.contenStyle2 }}>
                                {dateFormat(rowData.EventDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy')}
                             </Text>
                             <Icon
                                name='chevron-thin-right'
                                style={styles.iconStyle}
                             />
                             <View 
                                style={styles.titleStyle}
                             >
                                <Text style={styles.contentStyle}>  
                                {rowData.Title}
                             </Text>
                             </View>                          
                         </View>                 
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>      
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using react-native-router-flux, I found setting duration={1} on your scene declaration results in skipping the transition animation:

```
<Scene key={'someScene'} component={SomeComponent} title="Some Title" duration={1}/>
```

I never tried passing `duration` as a prop but I think there's no reason it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But stopping animation is not my intention at all. As you can see in the picture that I attached in the link above, my purpose is render new scene on the right side of split view but should remaining the scene in the left side.

Comment: Sorry for that. I misunderstood your question. I'll leave it here anyway, Might come useful for other developers.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out after 1 day. 
Thanks to Redux, all I need is create another Action creator and then pass rowData to it, after that I dispatch action again to receive state back.
I do not need to use replace or reset, Actions.SCENE_KEY is enough
The right side displays data like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

While calling the scene you should use `Actions.SCENE_NAME({type: replace | reset})` in order to disable push effect(animation) in transaction. The replace|reset just don't push anything in the stack of scenes they replaces the current scene with the scene you need in that place...

It works similar to the react native's navigator.. In that if you push or pop something it shows the transaction effect but does not show any effect when replace is used..

Cheers :)

Comment: I apply your solution, but simulator complains: 'action type should be defined'

Comment: what did you exactly wrote ?